# Styling the actual div element vs styling the div class/ID

Tags: css

Suppose you have a single div on an empty page that you want to style. Nothing else on the page but this div with class 'wrapper'. What's the difference between styling the element `div{styles;}` and styling its class `.wrapper{styles;}`? In certain situations, I've seen results vary between the two, even though I'm convinced that they should achieve the same results.

Am I right, or are there circumstances which involve using one over the other? Forget that selecting `div` will select all divs in this case.

Comment: Can you show some examples where the results between the two are different?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: If in the future, you wanted to add more DOM elements to that page, you'd have to revert to the `.wrapper` method *anyway* as you *may* not want to have those new DOM elements inherit those `div` styles. Specifying class names for CSS is a **good** practice.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words:
Usually you add CSS styles to classes except when you want all / most of the elements of specified tag to look/behave in certain way. Might be a good idea to style `a`, `p`, `body` tags to get consistent design across all site, but not so good idea to style `div`, `span` elements as their usage most probably will be different in different places.